# Error message: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, linq, generics, type-conversion

I have the following C# source: (asp.net version:3.5)

```
 //map is from 'string' type
 map = string.Join("", TrackMap.Split('|').Select(x => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"lightview\"><img src=\"{0}\" style=\"margin-right:30px;\" width=\"120\" height=\"80\"/>gh</a>", x)));
```

The problem is that I get this error message:

> Argument '2': cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'

And the error message:

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])'
>   has some invalid arguments

My qustion is how can I fix it? (maybe add some code in the web.config file? add 'using'-someting?)

Comment: Beginning from .NET 4.0 `String.Join()` accepts `IEnumerable<string>` for second parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are in .NET 3.5 which has not yet supported `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`, but supports `Join(String, Object[])`, so, you just need to call `ToArray` method in order to convert `IEnumerable` to `Array`:

```
map = string.Join("", TrackMap.Split('|').Select(x => string.Format("...", x))
                                         .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

[`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with the overload that takes an `IEnumerable<String>` was new in .NET 4, so you cannot use it in 3.5.

So this should work:

```
map = string.Join("", TrackMap.Split('|')
            .Select(x => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"lightview\"><img src=\"{0}\" style=\"margin-right:30px;\" width=\"120\" height=\"80\"/>gh</a>", x)
            .ToArray()));
```