# checking for values in multiple if statement and storing multiple comments based on results

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone give me an example of the best way to return multiple comments from an if statement?

```
  protected string CheckFacility(int FacilityId)
{
    var cfacility = new List<string>();
    BuildingPresenter b = new BuildingPresenter();
    FunctionalAreaPresenter f = new FunctionalAreaPresenter();
    if (b.GetBuildings(FacilityId) != null)
    {
        cfacility.Add("There are Functional Areas associated with this facility. ");
    }


    if (f.GetFunctionalAreas(FacilityId) != null) 
    {
        cfacility.Add("There are Functional Areas associated with this facility. ");
    }

    var cfacilitystring = string.Join(",", cfacility);
```

I'm getting these errors.

Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Error   4   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string[]'

Comment: huh? You have a 3 condition if statement, what does this have to do with returns? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, you can return multiple values in various different ways. You need to give us a clearer understanding of what you're trying to do and what you've tried before we can answer the question though.

Comment: You can have only one return from a method.  In the case above, it sounds like you're trying to store selected options - so unless it only matters if the shirt is black, large and has long sleeves (which would be a strange condition to have), I'd create an object to store all the selected options and return that object.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the code you've written, or attempt to write some code and show where it's not doing what you want it to do. It doesn't have to compile, just has to accurately convey what you're trying to accomplish so we'll know how to help you.

Comment: Let's say the color, sizes, or shirt type didn't matter.  I want to give the user a message based on the properties thats present.  So the message can return any combination like color and size only or maybe just the shirt type.  I'm just trying to figure out the best way to do this.  I'm trying to check if these properties are present .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var shirtAttributes = new List<string>();
if (shirt.IsBlack)
{
    shirtAttributes.Add("black");
}
if (shirt.IsLarge)
{
    shirtAttributes.Add("large");
}
if (shirt.IsLongSleeve)
{
    shirtAttributes.Add("long sleeve");
}
var shirtAttributesString = string.Join(",", shirtAttributes);
```

Output is something like: "black, long sleeve" or "black" or "large, long sleeve"

Comment: I'm getting these errors.  Would you be able to help? Thanks!

Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string[]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087071/error-message-cannot-convert-from-system-collections-generic-ienumerable-to

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to deal with that, you can create a class and override the `ToString()` method:

```
  public class Shirt{

    public Shirt(string color, string size, string sleeve)
    {
     Color =color;
     Size=size;
     Sleeve=sleeve;
     }
    public string Color {get;set;}
    public string Size {get;set}
    public string Sleeve {get;set}


    public override string ToString(){

     return string.Format("shirt is color :{0} , size :{1} and shleeve: {2}",Color,Size,Sleeve )

    }

  }
```

So when you run your program after initializing your class with values

```
Shirt myShirt = new Shirt("black","large","long");
if(myShirt.Color=="black"&& myShirt.Size=="large" && myShirt.Sleeve=="long")
{
 return myShirt.ToString(); 
 }
else{
 return "no match";//or want you want
 }
```

Hope it will help.